# How do I write unicode charcaters in console mode?

Tags: console, unicode, input

I know that I'm available to write unicode characters in a terminal application by pressing *ctrl+shift+u + unicode hex value*, but I don't know how to input ` (the grave accent for example), or any other unicode character when I switch to console mode by pressing *ctrl+alt+f1* .

Comment: I think it uses Alt + decimal value: Alt+64 produces @.

Comment: Have you tried entering `gucharmap` in a terminal window? You'll get a GUI with a whole list of symbols. If you click on "General Punctuation", for example, on the left you'll get a grid of symbols. Double-click on the one you want and then click `copy` from the bottom right corner. Then, go to the terminal window you want and paste with `control + shift + v`.

Comment: Vim uses digraphs, which include é. Should work in console as well.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>0060</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> hold during all the process) → `

@solarc: <kbd>Alt</kbd> is a Microsoft Windows solution.

Comment: This works only on X terminals, not on the console, which is what the question was about.

Comment: Upvote for both answer and question - I didn't know about this trick. :-)